# NodeJS: insert text to a specific index in a file

Tags: node.js

I'm working with a 13GB file.

Is it possible to insert a text in a file, at a specific index? I tried the following code but it always overwrites the content instead of prepending it:

```js
const fd = fs.openSync('./file.txt', 'w');

const text = Buffer.from('some text');

fs.write(fd, text, 0, text.byteLength, 0, () => {})
```

Comment: Theoretically you could read the whole file, insert your new text via traditional string manipulation and then rewrite the whole file with the new complete string.
The question is weather the system that will run your program is capable of handling a 13GB string chunk within its limitations.

Comment: Limited memory, can't do that unfortunately.

Comment: You will have to rewrite every byte that occurs after your write position, it's the same as inserting a value into the middle of an array. Can I ask the use case?

Comment: You could get around memory limitations by chunking the data into blocks, say of 1GB each. Read the original file 1 chunk at a time and either append or shift characters based on the block, then write that block by appending it on a new collector file. By the end the collector file should replace the original one. 
It is a cumbersome solution, but I couldnt find anything in the FS api or any npm package to do this out of the box.